# How to Show a Title instead of URL when reading a NFC tag

Tags: nfc, reader

Prerequisite
- NTAG215 NTAG 215 25mm NFC Stickers
- NFC Tools
- NXP Tag Writer

I have tried to use the above apps to write a url to my NFC tags. However, I can't find a way to hide the url and show text 'Title' on iOS devices when the tag is scanned. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Write a Smart Poster(text+URL) record instead of writing a simple URL.

If you are using NXP TagWriter, add your desired title in the "Description(Optional)" section while writing a link record.

[image: NXP TagWriter Screenshot]